# Using IF statements to apply an email address depending on teacher name

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-workspace, form-mule

I am attempting to create a sign in sheet for students when they are sent to a "calming" room. The idea is that when they reach the room, they enter their name and select their teacher's name from a drop down list.

I am using Form-mule to automatically send an email to the teacher the student selected saying that they checked into the calming room. However, Form-mule only allows you to set up 15 templates and as we have more than 15 teachers and I cannot expect a 3rd grader to be able to remember their teachers email address, I was hoping I could create a nested `IF` statement which will compare the teachers name the student selected and to enter an email address in a separate column of the Google Sheet.

The formula I have been using is:

```
=IF(D2 = “Mrs.Winehouse”, ”mwinehouse@aurorak12.org”, 
IF(D2 = ”Billie Eilish”, ”biellish@aurorak12.org”, 
IF(D2 = ”Jay Cutler”, ”jcutler@aurorak12.org”,“”)))
```

`D2` is the row of the Google Sheet where the Teacher Name info populates.
Unfortunately, I keep receiving a parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct except **you should be using straight double quotes (`" "`) instead of curly double (`“ ”`) quotes**.

This means your formula should be:

```
=IF(D2 = "Mrs.Winehouse", "mwinehouse@aurorak12.org", 
   IF(D2 = "Billie Eilish", "biellish@aurorak12.org", 
       IF(D2 = "Jay Cutler", "jcutler@aurorak12.org","")))
```

## Straight `" "` VS curly `“ ”`

Please read more about quotes on [straight and curly quotes](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html).
Curly quotes are also reffered as smart quotes.

You most likely created the formula in a program like Microsoft Word or an app like Google Docs and then copied it on to the cell.
When creating a formula, create it within a cell by double clicking on it.

*I did not edit your post so you can compare the difference*.

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much.

Comment: I am attempting to do this for 50+ names. Would I be able to do it in an editor such as Atom and copy paste it into the sheet?

Comment: Yes you would. [Atom](https://atom.io/) is a source code editor so you would not have any issues. In any case just rty it on just one name and `Copy-Paste` to find out.

Comment: Oh it worked right away. You called it as well. Google Docs was what I was using. I'm a bit new to all of this so I very much appreciate the help.